# Server Socket only print after client socket close

Tags: sockets, serversocket

I am implementing a java multi-threaded server. Whatever the client write to the socket stream does not get printed out on the server side. Data is only get printed after I terminate the client thread. What is the problem?
Here is my client code to send data:

```
BufferWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream() , 
                             "UTF-8" ) );
writer.write(curr.substring(3));
writer.flush();
```

Code on the server:

```
    public class ThreadedEchoServer
{  
   public static void main(String[] args )
   {  
      try
      {  
         int i = 1;
         ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8189);

         while (true)
         {  
            Socket incoming = s.accept();
            System.out.println("Spawning " + i);
            Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler(incoming, i);
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.start();
            i++;
         }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {  
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}

/**
   This class handles the client input for one server socket connection. 
*/
    class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable
    { 
       /**
          Constructs a handler.
          @param i the incoming socket
          @param c the counter for the handlers (used in prompts)
       */
       public ThreadedEchoHandler(Socket i, int c)
       { 
          incoming = i; counter = c; 
       }

       public void run()
       {  
          try
          {  
             try
             {
                InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outStream = incoming.getOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Server Running");
                Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream);         
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true /* autoFlush */);

                out.println( "Hello! Enter BYE to exit." );

                // echo client input
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done && in.hasNextLine())
                {  
                   String line = in.nextLine();
                   System.out.println(line);
                   out.println("Echo: " + line);            
                   if (line.trim().equals("BYE"))
                      done = true;
                }
             }
             finally
             {
                incoming.close();
             }
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {  
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Use `BufferedWriter.newline()` after calling `write().` At present `readLine()` is blocking waiting for a newline or EOS, and the EOS only happens when the client closes the socket.